# Is it safe to use size_t to shift vector index?

Tags: c++, integer

I prefer to use size_t to deal with vector index. But when shifting index, is it safe? For example,

```
size_t n = 10000000;
vector<int> v(n);

size_t i = 500000;
size_t shift = 20000;
int a = v(i - (-1) * shift); // Is this ok? what is `(-1) * shift` type, size_t?
int b = v(-shift + i); // Is this ok? what is `-shift` type, size_t?
```

Comment: `vector<T>` indexes are `vector<T>::size_type` in type, which is *usually* `size_t`, but, you *should* be using `size_type` instead of `size_t` directly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Is that the same as size_t?

Comment: `size_type` is defined as: "size_type can represent any non-negative value of difference_type". And `difference_type` is: "identical to the
difference type of X::iterator and X::const_iterator". That's saying that it's a type that can represent the difference between any two addresses in the vector. `size_t`, by definition, must meet that requirement.

Comment: You have well defined unsigned (modulo) arithmetic. But watch possible unintended conversions to signed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying a `size_t` with `(-1)` is safe, it wraps around the maximum value of `size_t`, as `size_t` is an unsigned type. So `(-1) * shift` is the same as `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max-shift+1`.

Answer (score 2):

Negating an `unsigned` quantity is a valid operation. Section 5.3.2 of C++11:

> The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its
>   value from 2^n , where n is the number of bits in the promoted
>   operand. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

So, this is "safe", in so far as this is defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Surely, you meant `v[...]`  instead of `v()`; `std::vector` has no `operator(int)`.

Anyway, empirically,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    unsigned foo = 1;
    cout<<(-1)*foo<<'\n';
    cout<<-foo<<'\n';
    cout<<foo*(-1)<<'\n';
    cout<<static_cast<int>(-foo)<<'\n';
    cout<<static_cast<int>(foo)*-1<<'\n';
}
```

yields:

```
4294967295
4294967295
4294967295
-1
-1
```

ergo a negated unsigned or an unsigned multiplied by -1 overflows by wrapping around its maximum value (this should be the theoretical behavior too).

As for passing size_t to 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at, if by chance `std::vector<T>::size_type` isn't `size_t` (unlikely but possible), passing a `size_t` within the bounds of your vector's `size()` should be safe and not lead to UB, as `size_t` must be large enough to index an array of any size.